# passing while loop value to another form

Tags: php

In the code bellow, I'm able to fetch values from the database. Now the retrieved values need to be passed to another form.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
  require('administrator/connect-db.php');
    $www_root = 'http://localhost/secure/cem/administrator/profile/';
  $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * from dealer_package_details");
  if(!$qry){echo mysql_error();}else{
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
        echo "<div class='col-sm-4 sm-margin-b-50'>";
        echo "<form action='test.php'>";
        echo "<div class='margin-b-20'>";
        echo "<div class='wow zoomIn' data-wow-duration='.3' data-wow-delay='.1s'>";
        echo '<img class="img-responsive" name="pport" src="', $www_root, '/', $row['pport'], '" alt="', $row['pport'], '"/>';
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<h3><a href='#' name='name_of_the_product'>" . $row['package_id'].$row['name_of_the_product']."</a></h3>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='book now'>";
        echo "</div>";

    }
  }
?>
```

The following code describes the second form where the values need to be passed.

**HTML:**

```
<form method="POST" action="insrt.php">
<input name="name_of_the_product" type="text" class="form-control name_of_the_product"  value="<?php echo $_POST["name_of_the_product"]; ?>" readonly/>
<input name="package_id" type="text" class="form-control package_id"  value="<?php echo $_POST["package_id"]; ?>" readonly/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
```

Comment: why do you want to get values from the DB and then send that to another page? If you just want to retrieve data to the client's page you can use AJAX very easily

Comment: In the first page i want to display list of services available , which get fetched from the DB, and if some one select that service then in the next page he/she will be able to get full description about the service which he opted and can book those selected services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use `input` hidden.

**PHP:**

```
...
echo "<input type='hidden' name='description' value='".$row['description]."' />";
...
```

**HTML:**

```
...
<input name="description" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['description']; ?>">
...
```